# Nest query equivalent for following ElasticSearch Query

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, .net-core, nest

I am new to dot net core. I am using https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/nest.html as my elastic search client.

I have following query for written in elastic search:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "term":{
                  "bookId.keyword":"c962ec04-6d25-4823-8e78-6d99d4072032"
               }
            },
            {
               "bool":{
                  "should":[
                     {
                        "match_phrase":{
                         "text":"Plants"
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
    }
}
```

While my NEST code is:

```cs
 var searchResponse = await _esClient.SearchAsync<Content>(s => s
                .Query(q => q
                    .Bool(b => b
                        .Must(m => m
                            .Term(terms => terms.Field(
                                    field => field.BookId.Suffix("keyword")
                                ).Value(bookId.ToString())
                            )
                        )
                        .Must(should =>
                            should.Match(mp => mp.Field(f => f.Text).Query(query))
                        )
                    )
                ));
```

However I am unable to get the intended result. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your NEST query does not exactly match the DSL query. Please modify your query to match the following.

```
var searchResponse = await _esClient.SearchAsync<Content>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Must(m => m
                .Term(terms => terms
                    .Field(field => field
                        .BookId.Suffix("keyword"))
                        .Value(bookId.ToString())
                ) && m.Bool(mb => mb
                    .Should(sh => sh
                        .MatchPhrase(mp => mp
                           .Field(f => f.Text).Query(query))))
                    )
                )
            ));
```

Answer (score 2):

You've *almost* got it. `Must()` takes a `params[]` of queries instead of calling it multiple times

```
var searchResponse = await _esClient.Search<Content>(s => s
   .Query(q => q
       .Bool(b => b
           .Must(m => m
               .Term(terms => terms.Field(
                       field => field.BookId.Suffix("keyword")
                   ).Value(bookId.ToString())
               ), m => m
               .Bool(mb => mb
                   .Should(sh => sh
                       .MatchPhrase(mp => mp
                           .Field(f => f.Text)
                           .Query(query)
                       )
                   )
               )
           )
       )
   )
);
```

[Mahesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62210141/1831) is the more succinct way of writing this query with operator overloading.